# Format of datasource view

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagridview

I have datagridview with sqlite connection.
Here is the code:

```
    dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source=data;");
    connection.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    SQLiteDataAdapter DA = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, connection);
    DA.Fill(sqlDS);
    dataGridView.DataSource = DS.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    dataGridView.Update();
```

I have datagridview with propertyName of columns like name in header table of sqlite. So data automatically insert in same name columns of datagridview.

I have question: How I can format data in columns?
For example: I have a column with header name: "Date". Same name in table of sqlite. There only date, but I want to see: "This" + date + " day!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `CellFormatting` event:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        e.Value = "This" + e.Value.ToString() + " day!";
}
```